# How to filter webform results

Tags: webforms

Can someone kindly tell me how to filter the webform results page? For example how can I show only the submissions where column X has value Y.

I am new to drupal but I am an experienced PHP programmer. If someone kindly points out he right webform hooks I will try to figure out the rest.

Suprisingly, google could not help me. But I'm sure that others have faced the same problem before. Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still need this information, but for the benefit of others...

1. You might want to look into the [webform_mysql_views](https://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) module.
2. If you are using drupal 7+, you can create a simple view of the "Webform Submissions" type. Then, under Fields you should be able to find Webform Submissions: Data Value field. Select that and then add the field you want to show up in your table. Do this for the rest of the fields you want. Finally, add the filters and/or sorts the very same way. NOTE: You might have to add a relationship (the very right drop-down) or two to show you relevant results.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Drupal contrib module called **Webform Selectable Filters** that extends views which will help you to create a view with dropdown list exposed filters instead of textfields.

- Download: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/neschi/2522034
- Step by step guide: http://www.neschi.com/blog/webform-selectable-filters